# I don't understnad this particular machine learning solution in python

Tags: python, scipy

I started learning machine learning in Python. I plotted the following graph following the author's notes:

[image]

One can notice that up until 3.5 weeks, there is a linear regression, and beyond it, there is a 2nd-order polynomial regression. The textbook question is: when will there be 100 000 requests/day?

The author says to use `fsolve`

```
reached_max = fsolve(myFunct-100000, x0=800)/(7*24)
```

The last point has x = 743 (hours). I am confused when the author says that we need to provide an initial starting position (e.g. 800). Why can it be any number after 743 and why does it have to be after 743? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see any model-definition so it's hard to answer. If the problem is non-convex, different starting-points can result in different results (as these algorithms only guarantee local-optima). Of course you can choose x0=1, but that can return a bad solution then. If the problem is convex, it does not matter (regarding the solution) but may take more time with some chosings of starting-points.

Comment: @sascha Hi Sasha! Thank you for your answer. I'm still struggling with it

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that x0 will serve as an educated initial guess. In general, [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) should work fine with its default value (x0 = 0), but in some cases will give a too far answer from the true root.

To better understand the math behind finding the root, I encourage to read about [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which serves as good introduction. Of course, fsolve uses more complicated and efficient techniques, but this should be a good baseline.

Hope I was clear and understood, and this has helped you!